# How can I specify the database to reverse engineer?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm following [this guide](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) on reverse engineering a database. The guide says it uses the `paramters.yml` file for the database parameters, but how can I override this? I have several connections listed in my `config.yml`, and I'd like to be able to choose one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `--em` parameter to specify which entity manager you want to use.

```
doctrine:mapping:convert [--filter="..."] [--force] [--from-database] [--extend[="..."]] [--num-spaces[="..."]] [--namespace[="..."]] [--em[="..."]] to-type dest-path
```

Comment: Thanks. My entity manager config information is in my `config.yml`. When I use the `--em=contract` option, it says it cannot find `config_contract.yml`. How do I point it to my main `config.yml` file?

Comment: Also, can you only reverse engineer certain tables?

Comment: Kind of. Delete the XML metadata files for the tables you don't want before importing them. Make sure there aren't any interpreted relations in the xml metadata before trying the import.

Comment: `convert` itself isn't working, because some tables don't have PKs.

Comment: You'll need to alter your tables to have a PK before this process will work. Easier method is to create a new schema, create the table you want on it, and then do convert.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign each Doctrine connection to its own Entity Manager, then you can specify the entity manager with the `--em="entity_manager_name"` flag. However, you will have to manually map each bundle to an entity manager. In the following example config, the other connection and entity manager are named *customer*

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Acme/CustomerBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --em="customer" --from-database --force
```

config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
           customer:
                driver:   %database_driver2%
                host:     %database_host2%
                port:     %database_port2%
                dbname:   %database_name2%
                user:     %database_user2%
                password: %database_password2%
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager:   default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    AcmeDemoBundle: ~
                    AcmeStoreBundle: ~
            customer:
                connection:       customer
                mappings:
                    AcmeCustomerBundle: ~
```

Comment: @SamSelikoff AcmeDemoBundle might use data from the default connection, but AcmeCustomerBundle might use data from a different database connection, so you'd need to map the bundles to the correct connection via the entity manager's `mappings` configuration.